# Adding a different prefix to two separate product categories

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am giving web design a go for the first time really as I am building a website for my Telephone Service and Signage Design company. I am using wordpress to build my website, my shop is a woocommerce shop and I am trying to add two different suffixes to the prices based on the category they are in. One suffix is per month and the other one is per hour. I am trying to do this using the code below in my child theme functions.php but I believe I have gone wrong with my code. Could you please help me to get the code correct?

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_html', 'conditional_price_suffix', 20, 2 );
function conditional_price_suffix( $price, $product ) {
$product_categories = array('telephone','signage');

if( has_term( $product_categories, 'telephone', $product->get_id() ) )
    $price .= ' ' . __('per month');

if( has_term( $product_categories, 'signage', $product->get_id() ) )
    $price .= ' ' . __('per hour');

return $price;

}
```

after giving in and looking on here, I also found this code although it looks like it should work it does not work with my woocommerce.

```
function conditional_price_suffix( $price, $product ) {
$product_id = $product->is_type('variation') ? $product->get_parent_id() 
: $product->get_id();
$product_categories = array('telephone');
$product_categories2 = array('signage');
if( has_product_categories( $product_categories, $product_id ) ) {
    $price .= ' ' . __('per month');
} elseif( has_product_categories( $product_categories2, $product_id ) ) 
{
    $price .= ' ' . __('per hour');
}
return $price;
}
```

Comment: Hi @Dan, when you say "I believe I have gone wrong with my code" it doesn't give us to work with. Can you define the problem as what you expect for results, either literally or a conceptual screenshot, along with the actual results?

Comment: Well my logic suggests this code should work but it does not. There is no suffix added to the woocommerce price for either category. So I would like to get this code to work so it adds a price suffix to both categories.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will work with very small changes on has_term() like this:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_html', 'conditional_price_suffix', 20, 2 );
function conditional_price_suffix( $price, $product ) {
    $product_id = $product->get_id();
    if( has_term('telephone','product_cat', $product_id ) )
        $price .= ' ' . __('per month');

    if( has_term('signage','product_cat', $product_id ) )
        $price .= ' ' . __('per hour');

    return $price;

}
```

Comment: Rajeev you are amazing, thank you ever so much, is there a way within this code to set the font size? and perhaps the vertical alignment as I would like it smaller and next to the price at the top :)

Comment: Thanks bro, I will glad for help you.

Comment: Yes you can add class and manage text/label according to class like this: $price .= ' ' . __('<span class="price-label>per month</span>'); try this hopefully it will work

Comment: . price-label{font-size:12px}